# I was incorrectly awarded the Sheriff badge today on Board and Card Games

Tags: support, badges, moderators

Today I got the [only Sheriff badge on Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/sheriff), which is not correct because we have never had a moderator election.

This happened exactly one year after I was briefly removed and then reinstated. That event reset the displayed date on which I became a mod, and I am guessing it also flipped a flag indicating whether I was elected or appointed.

Comment: This isn't really a bug in my opinion. According to the [badge criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/377214), you served continuously as a moderator on a non-beta site for one year. The fact that the general system description has the word "elected" is a bit incorrect, and has been reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331854/update-sheriff-badge-description-to-reflect-the-existence-of-elected-pro-tem-mod). (The bullet about not qualifying if one gained their current diamond in beta I added in response to this question, but you still met it.)

Comment: Huh, that does explain it. My timer was reset fairly soon after BCG left beta, so according to the system I am the only moderator on the site who gained the diamond outside of beta.