# Add launch date to Area 51 proposal page

Tags: feature-request, area-51, dates, graduating-sites

Currently, the launch date of a site is only shown as a relative timestamp. That's fine if this [happened recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/295232), but for example [Bitcoin's page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30763/bitcoin) says the site was launched "1 year ago". That's rather vague; one has to find the [graduation post](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/876/42185) on a site's own Meta to see the actual launch date (1 year and 10(!) months ago).

Most relative timestamps on Stack Exchange can be hovered over to show a UTC date/time, e.g. the other ones in that column (see below). That would be an option; alternatively, the launch date could be added as a separate 'event' just above 'public beta start'.

[image]