# Exact dates of stages before launch of a website

Tags: support, area-51, beta-sites, private-beta, graduating-sites

Is it possible to know the exact dates at which Stack Exchange websites have passed each of the development stages before being launched officially? I refer to date of proposal, date of commitment, date of private beta, etc.

In the Area 51 website an approximate date is recorded (i.e. 6 years ago,..for example for Stack Overflow in Russian, this is recorded on the right column [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168?phase=beta)), but I was wondering if I could find the exact dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most relative timestamps on Stack Exchange sites, you can hover over them to show the exact date:

[image]

This won't work for the 'Launched 3 years ago', I've proposed a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332028/295232) to change that. Meanwhile, one has to find the appropriate (graduation) post on the site's own Meta site. It's [this one](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1985/223536) for ru.SO; another case where the tooltip proves its worth since you can easily see that "11 дек '15" is 2015-12-11, i.e. December 11th, 2015.