# Are all non-Beta sites displayed in the footer?

Tags: discussion, design, stackexchange.com, footer, full-sites

When on summer 2019 many sites made it out of beta [I noticed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331736/209901) that only graduated sites showed in the footer of all Stack Exchange sites. For instance, see [a snapshot of Meta.SE from March 8, 2019](https://web.archive.org/web/20190308213845/https://meta.stackexchange.com/) on the Culture/Recreation section:

> [image]

Now I just noticed the footer included way more sites:

> [image]

One site I focus on, Spanish.SE, now does show in the list. It did not in the past, but it is one of the 29 sites that made it out of beta in summer 2019. However, a still beta site like Italian.SE does not. However, if I click on *more (16)* (on the right corner) it sends me to the full list of sites in https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation.

For this, I wonder: all non-Beta sites showing now in the footer? (I ask because I don't have an automated way to see which sites are of each kind, apart from opening them all and checking if they have "Beta" in their name).

Comment: @Mast what I wonder if all these 16 are the Culture / Recreation sites that are still in Beta. I went through the list and apparently it is the case, so not sure if now they display `More (X)` with X being the number of Beta sites on that specific section.