# Default election question about reaching 10k or 20k rep is inaccurate for sites with beta-level privileges

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, privileges, election, beta-sites

One of the default questions in election questionnaires is

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

([source](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2906/5345))

That was (almost) correct at the time where elections were only held on graduated sites. (The 'almost' is because privilege levels are usually only increased when the site received a custom design, which used to happen quite soon thereafter.)

However, we have a lot of elections on beta sites these days, or on sites which graduated but may [keep beta-level privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/295232).

For those sites, can the default question be changed to something like

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching enough reputation to [access moderator tools](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) or become a [trusted user](/help/privileges/trusted-user)?

It could stay how it is right now on sites with default privilege levels, of course. On the other hand, occasional users may think "what's so special about 10k/20k reputation?" and I'm sure they would appreciate those links as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of January 30<sup>th</sup>, 2023 the default question has now changed to reflect the proposal in this question.

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching enough reputation to [access moderator tools](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) or become a [trusted user](/help/privileges/trusted-user)?

This has changed on **all sites**, not just beta sites.